# git push to gerrit server doesn't work when setting git remote set-url --push, but works if I type in the URL manually

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push

I am having trouble pushing my code from git to gerrit.  First I checked out the code like so:

`git clone ssh://user@location.com:22/path/to/code`

Then I tried setting up a push url like so:

`git remote set-url --push origin "someotherlocation.com:/path/to/code HEAD:refs/for/master"`

When I do `git push` it returns this error:

```
fatal: '/path/to/code HEAD:refs/for/master': not a Gerrit project
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, if I just type in

`git push someotherlocation.com:/path/to/code HEAD:refs/for/master`

it gets pushed to the gerrit server.  Why is this, and what am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the URI scheme? Is it `ssh://`? Does it help to include it in the URI?

Comment: There is no URI scheme, it's just `git push someotherlocation.com:/path/to/code HEAD:refs/for/master`.  When I put ssh:// it gave me an error that said: ssh: Could not resolve hostname someotherlocation.com:: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I also tried adding a username and port number with the ssh:// and it still didn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git remote` command sets the push URL to, literally, `someotherlocation.com:/path/to/code HEAD:refs/for/master`. A push URL is expected to be just the URL. The push refspec (`HEAD:refs/for/master`) is not part of the URL. If the goal is to avoid having to type the refspec every time I suggest you look into setting up a Git alias or investigate the `remote.<name>.push` option for .gitconfig (see [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)).

Comment: Thank you!  I set `git config --local remote.origin.push HEAD:refs/for/master` and `git remote set-url --push origin someotherlocation.com:/path/to/code` and now it works when I just type `git push`.  Again, many thanks!